# Exception with Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I have this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.requestFocus(WebViewClassic.java:10003)
        at android.webkit.WebView.requestFocus(WebView.java:2133)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2382)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2338)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2382)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2338)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2382)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2341)
        at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6538)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1899)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1110)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4472)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But it doesn't tell me what line it happened on or anything else. Any idea how to debug this?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: You can always try to use the android debugger to go step by step. That will pretty much tell u where you are getting the exception . More often than not running code in debug mode will help you deal with such problems.

Comment: You can see if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143831/nullpointerexception-on-webview-webview-requestfocus) helps

Comment: @rockstar I have not been able to reproduce this error :(